# REGEX for phone number

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to create regex match for phone number in *jquery*, for exactly this format

+XXX XXX XXX XXX, where X is digit.

I created this

```
var regEx = '[+]{1}[\d]{3}[ ]{1}[\d]{3}[ ]{1}[\d]{3}[ ]{1}[\d]{3}';
        var val = jQuery.trim($('#phone_number').val())
        if (val.match(regEx)) {
            alert('good');
        }
        else
            alert('bad');
        }
```

Any assistance will be helpful.

Comment: please look at the link. it has almost all regex combinations.


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?rq=1

Comment: i dont want all of them..i want exactly this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, but there are a few "unnecessaries", and you're missing anchors assuming the phone number is not part of a larger string (and this is for validation).

```
^\+\d{3} \d{3} \d{3} \d{3}$
```

Comment: changed to var regEx = '^\+\d{3} \d{3} \d{3} \d{3}$'; now i get error invalid regular expression

Comment: Well, you're using it as a string... Wrap it in `/` instead

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var regEx = /^\+\d{3}(?: \d{3}){3}$/;
```